# Spacy es_core_news_sm model not loading

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm trying to use Spacy for `pos tagging` in Spanish, for this I have checked the official documentation and also have read various post in Stackoverflow nonetheless neither has worked to me.

I have Python 3.7 and Spacy 2.2.4 installed and I'm running my code from a jupyter notebook

So as [documentation](https://spacy.io/models) suggests I tried:

From my terminal:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

This gave the result:

```
Download and installation successful
```

Then in my jupyter notebook:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")
```

And I got the following error:

```
ValueError: [E173] As of v2.2, the Lemmatizer is initialized with an instance of Lookups containing the lemmatization tables. See the docs for details: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer#init
```

Additionally, I tried:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")
```

And this gave me a different error:

```
OSError: Can't find model 'es_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory
```

Could you please help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You downloaded English model. In order to use Spanish model, you have to download it `python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm`

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the right model you can try import it as follow

```
import spacy
import es_core_news_sm
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
```